# Order a Sequelize query by a join table using model instance getters

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I would like to order my results from a join table property using Sequelize. Most of the answers I've seen on stack overflow aren't explaining how to order by a join table when using the model's `getter` methods. And the way I'm trying to use it is returning inconsistent results...sometimes it returns the right order but other times it doesn't. This has me stumped.

I have an app that has `Playlists` and `Tracks`. A user can add `Tracks` to a `Playlist` in a specific `order`.

Given the following models:

**Playlist**

```
const Playlist = sequelize.define('Playlist', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Playlist.associate = function(models) {
    Playlist.belongsToMany(models.Track, { through: models.PlaylistTrack, foreignKey: "playlistID", otherKey: "trackID" });
  };
```

**Track**

```
const Track = sequelize.define('Track', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Track.associate = function(models) {
    Track.belongsToMany(models.Playlist, { through: models.PlaylistTrack, foreignKey: "trackID", otherKey: "playlistID" });
  };
```

This is a `many-to-many` relationship, so I've created a join table (make sure to note the `order` property):

**PlaylistTrack**

```
  const PlaylistTrack = sequelize.define('PlaylistTrack', {
    playlistID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    trackID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    order: DataTypes.INTEGER <-- important property
  }, {});
  PlaylistTrack.associate = function(models) {
  };
```

In my api, I have a method `getTracksByPlaylist()` where I query for the `playlist` instance and then use the `getTracks()` `getter` to return all the tracks for that playlist:

```
async getTracksByPlaylist(playlistId) {
    // get instance of Playlist
    const playlist = await Playlist.findOne({
        where: { id: playlistId }
    });

    // use the available getter (getTracks) on the Playlist instance
    var response = await playlist.getTracks({
        include: [{ model: Playlist }],
        order: [[ Playlist, PlaylistTrack, "order", "ASC" ]]
    });
}
```

In my database join table, I set the `order` property. Therefore, in this example, I would expect to observe results that show tracks in the order of 0,1,2,3,4...etc. However, every once in a while, it will display the results **not** in `ASCENDING` order. Have I hit a race condition of sorts? What is the best way to return results using `Sequelize` `getters` and ordering through a join table?

---

If you're curious, here are the queries printed from the command line:

**This one uses the method described above and produces inconsistent results**

```
SELECT `Track`.`id`,`Track`.`title`, `Track`.`createdAt`, `Track`.`updatedAt`, `Playlists`.`id` AS `Playlists.id`, `Playlists`.`title` AS `Playlists.title`, `Playlists`.`createdAt` AS `Playlists.createdAt`, `Playlists`.`updatedAt` AS `Playlists.updatedAt`, `Playlists->PlaylistTrack`.`playlistID` AS `Playlists.PlaylistTrack.playlistID`, `Playlists->PlaylistTrack`.`trackID` AS `Playlists.PlaylistTrack.trackID`, `Playlists->PlaylistTrack`.`order` AS `Playlists.PlaylistTrack.order`, `Playlists->PlaylistTrack`.`createdAt` AS `Playlists.PlaylistTrack.createdAt`, `Playlists->PlaylistTrack`.`updatedAt` AS `Playlists.PlaylistTrack.updatedAt`, `PlaylistTrack`.`playlistID` AS `PlaylistTrack.playlistID`, `PlaylistTrack`.`trackID` AS `PlaylistTrack.trackID`, `PlaylistTrack`.`order` AS `PlaylistTrack.order`, `PlaylistTrack`.`createdAt` AS `PlaylistTrack.createdAt`, `PlaylistTrack`.`updatedAt` AS `PlaylistTrack.updatedAt` 
FROM `Tracks` AS `Track` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `PlaylistTracks` AS `Playlists->PlaylistTrack` 
INNER JOIN `Playlists` AS `Playlists` ON `Playlists`.`id` = `Playlists->PlaylistTrack`.`playlistID`) ON `Track`.`id` = `Playlists->PlaylistTrack`.`trackID` 
INNER JOIN `PlaylistTracks` AS `PlaylistTrack` ON `Track`.`id` = `PlaylistTrack`.`trackID` 
AND `PlaylistTrack`.`playlistID` = 3 
ORDER BY `Playlists->PlaylistTrack`.`order` ASC;
```

Looks like it's doing something weird with a double inner join?

Using traditional methods I found on Stackoverflow, I can get consistent and correct results:

```
const response = await Playlist.findOne({
    where: { id: 3 },
    include: [{ model: Track }],
    order: [[Track, PlaylistTrack, "order", "ASC"]]
})
```

From the `response` I can extract `Tracks` in correct `ASCENDING` order via `response.Tracks`.

**This creates the following accurate query**

```
SELECT `Playlist`.`id`, `Playlist`.`title`, `Playlist`.`createdAt`, `Playlist`.`updatedAt`, `Tracks`.`id` AS `Tracks.id`, `Tracks`.`title` AS `Tracks.title`, `Tracks`.`createdAt` AS `Tracks.createdAt`, `Tracks`.`updatedAt` AS `Tracks.updatedAt`, `Tracks->PlaylistTrack`.`playlistID` AS `Tracks.PlaylistTrack.playlistID`, `Tracks->PlaylistTrack`.`trackID` AS `Tracks.PlaylistTrack.trackID`, `Tracks->PlaylistTrack`.`order` AS `Tracks.PlaylistTrack.order`, `Tracks->PlaylistTrack`.`createdAt` AS `Tracks.PlaylistTrack.createdAt`, `Tracks->PlaylistTrack`.`updatedAt` AS `Tracks.PlaylistTrack.updatedAt` 
FROM `Playlists` AS `Playlist` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `PlaylistTracks` AS `Tracks->PlaylistTrack` 
INNER JOIN `Tracks` AS `Tracks` ON `Tracks`.`id` = `Tracks->PlaylistTrack`.`trackID`) ON `Playlist`.`id` = `Tracks->PlaylistTrack`.`playlistID` 
WHERE `Playlist`.`id` = 3 
ORDER BY `Tracks->PlaylistTrack`.`order` ASC;
```